# JqGrid setCell method, inserts blank row in the grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, javascript-framework

I have a portion of code to update a cell value like this:

```
jQuery("#myGridDiv").jqGrid('setCell', myRowToEdit, myColToEdit, myNewValue);
```

that's about it, and sometimes it happens that a blank 'dummy' row is inserted at the end of the grid, this behavior is somewhat random but occurs often,

any help will be really appreciated

Comment: The most likely reason is that you call this "portion of code to update a cell value" too often. (Example unexpected triggering via event-binding or similar). Show more code to verify

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is what is causing the problem? I read through the jqGrid 3.6.4 source code and nothing really jumps out. Perhaps you have some other code on your jqGrid (or application) that is causing this problem.

I suggest either removing code to try to isolate the problem, or for you to post more code in your question.

Comment: Yes Justin, you are totally right, the issue was caused by other part of the code and had nothing to do with setCell,

basically I had to jqGrids one showing incomplete logs and the other showing complete ones, so when the user 'completed' one of the incomplete logs, the row in that jqgrid was deleted, and then a row was inserted in the copleted logs jqgrid.

The completed logs can be edited, and the only the value of one cell was updated, I had bas logic in one case, that when you were editing completed logs, did the db update, but was calling the js routine that added rows,

Thank you Justin